# windows store app , Simulator keep loading ( vs2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

i am developing an app for windows 8 metro style, i e , window store app,

but when i select

[image]

the simulator is keep loading, i am not able to see my app, not even application name

i went to google search but i am not able to find correct solution, please help me

i want to see my app on simulator

[image]

i looked here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx

, and in comments and most people have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the simulator directly from local folder

Path: 
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe"

If you are getting same issue look at this blog [http://blog.themagicsoftware.com/2012/11/cant-start-windows-8-app-in-simulator-from-visual-studio-2012-it-loads-forever.html ].

**Edit:** Have you look at the blog & their solutions.

> ```
> Possible Solutions:
> ```
>
> I found in forums the following 2 solutions:
>
> Changing the following key in the registry to 1 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
>   Server\fDenyChildConnections Updating NVIDIA drivers.

Here is the post from MSFT people
[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9e2fe728-7105-4399-b742-9786103e1618/vs-2012-windows-store-application-simulator-freezing-at-loading-screen?forum=toolsforwinapps#28b30fd9-a543-4650-9b64-ace94f4b0456 ]

You can see the last option for you is reinstall the Visual Studio 2012.

let me know if it is solved ur issue or not..

Comment: i tired that, and issue is still same :)

Comment: i cannot reinstall vs2012, bro ! it's painful :)

Comment: @Yeap. It is. But it is last option for anyone. I hope you tried everything they suggested in the blog links:)